# Tool for images and videos sync to clients

Tags: image, apache-flex, video, synchronization, offline

I support a Flex client - server and the clients are offline most of the time.  The idea is the users will work with the client all day and connect to the network via and sync data.  The client's does not currently have any sort of media in it such as products pictures or videos however we would like to implement this.

I am looking for a reasonably priced tool or open source that can help sync images/videos over the network by basically synchronizing a master folder on the server to a folder on the client(s)

I have tried SyncToy from Microsoft but the reviews are not very good for the volume of data involved

I am looking at MediaTransfer from Telelogos which is good but over priced

I feel there must be a better tool or even a better way - I am open to suggestion for a different approach.
thanks

Comment: @RIAstar...look am here to find answers to my problem...no beef please

Comment: Fair enough. But you should 'reward' the people that take the time to provide you with their answers (that's how I should have delivered the message the first time; sorry, I got a little carried away). That being said, now that I actually read your question, I see that it is not a programming question, so you should ask it in the appropriate place. I believe there is a StackExchange site for software questions.

Comment: thanks for the reminder...you made your point, but you still should have focused on why I am here and maybe add it as a gentle reminder - the gangster attitude does not help anyone.  That said, I will post in StackExchange

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few media servers:

- [Adobe Media Server](https://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family.html)
- [Gnump3D](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnump3d/)
- [Darwin Streaming Server](http://dss.macosforge.org/)
- [Windows Media Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727428)
- [LEADTOOLS Multimedia Developer Toolkit](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia.htm)
- [IceCast Streaming Server](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.3.3/)

And here is a client:

- [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/about/)

Adobe has a tutorial on how to integrate its product with mobile clients:

- [Adobe Media Server: Streaming Video to iOS](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/streaming-video-ios.html)

Mozilla has a tutorial on setting up media files that support adaptive streaming:

- [Setting up Adaptive Streaming Media Sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Setting_up_adaptive_streaming_media_sources)

Haxe has a tutorial on their experimental RTMP server:

- [Haxe Video](https://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/wiki/Help)

Apple has a tutorial for the commercial version of Darwin Streaming Server:

- [Preparing movies for Internet delivery](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT2438)

Microsoft has a tutorial for the streaming addon to IIS:

- [Apple HTTP Live Streaming with IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/learn/media/live-smooth-streaming/apple-http-live-streaming-with-iis-media-services)

Finally, there's a tutorial on running Gnump3d as a Windows service:

- [Installing Gnump3d as a Windows service](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnump3d/Gnump3d-Service-on-Windows.txt)